# Переменные в Go при вызове db.Exec

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, golang

Когда я использую конструкции вида:

```
result, err := db.Exec("CREATE...")
```

`result` остается невостребованным. Следовательно, ругань от Go. Пришлось использовать такое вот:

```
_ = result
```

Костыльно. Конструкции вида:

```
_, err := db.Exec("CREATE...")
```

Выбивают ошибку:

```
no new variables on left side of :=
```

При этом, при использовании подобной конструкции, скажем, с `if` - все работает:

```
if _, ok := err.(*url.Error); !ok
```

Как реализовать это без костылей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:=` следует использовать только когда у вас новые переменные. В данном случае компилятор вам говорит, что выше вы уже объявили `err`, так что вы должны писать:

```golang
_, err = db.Exec(query)
```

Comment: Супер! Заработало, спасибо